# '[' and ']' in Regex PHP

Tags: php

I want to get the string between the characters '[' and ']'.

Althought this, it doesn't work when I put it in Regex "`/[(.*?)\]/s`".

```
 <?php
    $s = '00:00:02 - *LOCAL* [Claire_Fortune] say atl least ty q.q';
    $matches = array();
    $t = preg_match('/[(.*?)\]/s', $s, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1]);
    ?>
```

Is there any hack-around this?

Comment: I am not very good with Regex, can you please put that into an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the opening bracket also.So replace

```
$t = preg_match('/[(.*?)\]/s', $s, $matches);
```

with

```
$t = preg_match('/\[(.*?)\]/s', $s, $matches);
```

Comment: Sorry, I have done so now, thank you for reminding me!